# How to profile TensorFlow 1.15 memory allocation in eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training YOLOv4. The training loop takes in a batch of images and a couple of NumPy arrays describing expected object detection boxes. YOLOv4 has a complicated custom loss function.

My training loop (simplified) looks like this:

```py
for batch in data:
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(batch.images, training=True)
    loss = compute_loss(pred, batch.target_outputs)
    if not tf.is_nan(loss).numpy().any():
      gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
      optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

As far as I can see, the shape of `batch.images` does not change.

Problem is after a few epochs I start getting `ResourceExhaustedError` because TensorFlow runs out of GPU memory in `pred = model(batch.images, training=True)` line.

I'd like to figure out what causes new memory to be allocated. Is there a way to get a snapshot of the entire GPU heap, or at least get the number of bytes that are currently allocated?